# Apache Camel - Error when calling a SOAP webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I try to send a POST request to a SOAP Webservice throw camel route, and i got this error message :

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for service {http://www.webserviceX.NET/}GlobalWeather.
```

This is the route:

```
<route id="my_Sample_Camel_Route_with_CXF">
       <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
       <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}"/>
       <to uri="cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdlURL=http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}GlobalWeather&amp;portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}GlobalWeatherSoap&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
       <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}"/>
</route>
```

service defenition in WSDL:

```
<wsdl:service name="GlobalWeather">
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
<soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap12" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
<http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
<http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"/"` at the end must be deleted.

it should be like this:

```
serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET}GlobalWeather&amp;
portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET}GlobalWeatherSoap
```